# Resizing Canvas with Scrollbar dynamically by using the layout_manager grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I built a canvas and I don't know why, I wont make it to resize with the frame.
Either something obvious is missing and by craftig all the stuff inside I lost my mind or something weird happens and I dont get it. Anyway here is my code, hope it can be clearify.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class my_figure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master,
                 width=450,height=590):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.width=width
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.update)

        #DownFrame
        self.body = tk.Frame(self, width=width,height=height,relief='sunken',bd=2)
        self.vscrbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.body)
        self.hscrbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.body,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.Display = tk.Canvas(self.body, width=width,height=height,
                                 background='#f0f0f0',highlightthickness=0,
                                 yscrollcommand=self.vscrbar.set,
                                 xscrollcommand=self.hscrbar.set)
        
        self.vscrbar.config(command=self.Display.yview)
        self.hscrbar.config(command=self.Display.xview)

        self.body.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky='nswe')
        self.vscrbar.grid(column=1,sticky='ns')
        self.hscrbar.grid(row=1,sticky='we')
        self.Display.grid(column=0,row=0,
                          sticky='nswe')

        
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def update(self, event):
        print(event.widget.winfo_width())
##        self.Header.config(width=event.width)
##        self.Button.config(width=event.width)
##        self.body.config(width=event.width)
##        self.Display.config(width=event.width)
        

        
figure = my_figure(root)
figure.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used nested parent container.Your `my_figure` is a widget inherit from `Frame`.And there are also a `Frame` widget in your `my_figure`.You need to set `columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure` for both of them.

Also need to use `sticky="nwes"` for your `figure`.

Though it could work normally,`pack` manager would be the best choice.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


class my_figure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        # self["bd"] = 10
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.update)

        # DownFrame
        self.body = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
        for i in range(self.body.grid_size()[1] + 1):
            self.body.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        for i in range(self.body.grid_size()[0] + 1):
            self.body.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        for i in range(self.grid_size()[1] + 1):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        for i in range(self.grid_size()[0] + 1):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.vscrbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.body)
        self.hscrbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.body, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.Display = tk.Canvas(self.body,
                                 background='#f0f0f0', highlightthickness=0,
                                 yscrollcommand=self.vscrbar.set,
                                 xscrollcommand=self.hscrbar.set)

        self.vscrbar.config(command=self.Display.yview)
        self.hscrbar.config(command=self.Display.xview)

        self.body.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe')
        self.vscrbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.hscrbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self.Display.grid(column=0, row=0,
                          sticky='nswe')

    def update(self, event):
        print(event.widget.winfo_width())


##        self.Header.config(width=event.width)
##        self.Button.config(width=event.width)
##        self.body.config(width=event.width)
##        self.Display.config(width=event.width)


figure = my_figure(root)
figure.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwes")
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```